# setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance (device only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

My app was working fine until recently, when the Sprite Scene began to crash after "return self;" it would display the error "-[BEGameScene setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10040de10'" before "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" this bug seems to only happen on a device; the ios simulator works fine.

The weird thing is that the bug doesn't seem to be in my code. I took an older, still working version, duplicated it directly from finder and when I ran that it crashed too.

Could it be a problem with Xcode 6 (which I recently downloaded)?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Sorry, here is the code

```
#import "BEGameScene.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface BEMainGameViewController : UIViewController <BEGameSceneDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <BEGameSceneDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

---

```
#import "BEMainGameViewController.h"
#import "BEGameScene.h"

@interface BEMainGameViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPanGestureRecognizer *control;
@end

@implementation BEMainGameViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = NO;
    skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    BEGameScene *scene = [BEGameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    scene.delegate = self;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background 1.tiff"]]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)unwindFromGame {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromGameScene" sender:self];
}



@end
```

---

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@protocol BEGameSceneDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)unwindFromGame;

@end

@interface BEGameScene : SKScene <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <BEGameSceneDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

---

```
#import "BEMainGameViewController.h"
#import "BEGameScene.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation BEGameScene {
    NSArray *location;
    int x_flower;
    int x_Trap1;
    int x_Trap2;
    int randNum;
    int speed;
    int score;
    int life;
    BOOL rad;
    BOOL collide;
    NSInteger interval;
    SKSpriteNode *sprite_bee;
    SKSpriteNode *sprite_flower;
    SKSpriteNode *sprite_flyTrap;
    SKSpriteNode *sprite_flyTrap2;
    SKSpriteNode *sprite_rad;
    SKSpriteNode *sprite_radGlow;
    NSTimer *timer;
    SKLabelNode *youLoseLabel;
    SKLabelNode *instruction;
    NSString *scoreText;
    NSString * honey;

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    life = 1;

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        //self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        SKSpriteNode *bgImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"BGImage"];
        bgImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:bgImage];

        //Bee movement
        SKTexture *texture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bee up.tiff"];
        SKTexture *texture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bee down.tiff"];
        SKTexture *texture3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Flower.tiff"];
        SKTexture *texture4 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Fly Trap.tiff"];
        SKTexture *texture5 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"radiation.png"];
        SKTexture *texture6 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"rad glow.png"];


        sprite_bee = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture1];
        sprite_bee.position = CGPointMake(160, 100);
        sprite_bee.zPosition = 100;
        sprite_bee.size = CGSizeMake(110, 110);

        SKAction *fly = [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[texture1,texture2] timePerFrame:.2];
        [sprite_bee runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:fly]];

        [self addChild:sprite_bee];

        collide = NO;
        //Plant creation

        speed = 100;
        score = 0;
        x_flower = 40;
        x_Trap1 = 160;
        x_Trap2 = 280;

        sprite_radGlow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rad glow.png"];
        sprite_radGlow.position = CGPointMake(100,3000);
        sprite_radGlow.size = CGSizeMake(140, 140);
        sprite_radGlow.zPosition = 50;

        SKAction *glow = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                              [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:.5],
                                              [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:.5],
                                              ]];

        [sprite_radGlow runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:glow]];

        [self addChild: sprite_radGlow];

        sprite_flower = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture3];
        sprite_flower.position = CGPointMake(40, 300);
        sprite_flower.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);

        [self addChild:sprite_flower];


        sprite_flyTrap = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture4];
        sprite_flyTrap.position = CGPointMake(160, 300);
        sprite_flyTrap.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);


        [self addChild:sprite_flyTrap];

        sprite_flyTrap2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture4];
        sprite_flyTrap2.position = CGPointMake(280, 300);
        sprite_flyTrap2.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);


        [self addChild:sprite_flyTrap2];

        sprite_rad = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture5];
        sprite_rad.position = CGPointMake(160, 3000);
        sprite_rad.size = CGSizeMake(500, 100);


        [self addChild:sprite_rad];

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Show some relevant code. And show how you declare the `delegate` property on your `BEGameScene` class.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the exception stack trace and give us a few clues as to how your app is constructed.  And also review all the places where you do `setDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

So I think your issue might be related to `SKScene` adding a [`delegate` field](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/delegate) in iOS 8.

I recommend renaming your internal delegate field to something else, like `gameSceneDelgate` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: had the same issue with a little game I wrote and the introduction of the delegate field made it crash for me too.